# Disk usage to show only select partitions?

Tags: debian, awk

I'd like to be able to only show disk usage for specific partitions in GB and a % after. Basically ignore swap, tmpfs, etc..

I'd also like to sum the disk usage amount and subtract from the total to get free space.

Right now I have something like this, but not sure how to use awk and select the partitions I want to count.

```
df -h | awk '$5 ~ /\%$/ print $1 " " $5}'
```

This is for a debian system.

Edit:

So figured out I can use / to limit the results, however, this only shows me how much is free.

```
df -h / | awk '{ a = $4 } END { print a }'
```

Comment: Why not simply `grep`?

Comment: Not familiar with the command

Comment: _"I'd also like to sum the disk usage amount and subtract from the total to get free space."_.  How is that different from what `df -h` already provides in the `Avail` column?

Comment: `df` should accept a mountpoint as an argument. It may even be a directory or a file below the mountpoint. The tool will then display information for the appropriate mountpoint only. Try it: `df -h /tmp` or `df -h /dev/urandom`. You can specify multiple arguments in that fashion.

Comment: You know there's `df -x tmpfs`, right?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with `awk`, but you are complicating the expression needlessly. All you need to output the file system, free space and percentage occupancy is:

```
df -h /|awk '{ print $1, $4, $5 }'
```

However, this will not align the headers with the data. To preserve the alignment, use something like:

```
df -h /|awk '{ printf "%-60s %6s %6s\n", $1, $4, $5 }'
```

Here I have used a wide first field because my system disc is listed by UUID. To show percentage free space instead of occupancy, you can use:

```
df -h /|awk '{ printf $5=="Use%"?"%-60s %6s   Free%%\n":"%-60s %6s %6s%%\n", $1, $4, 100-$5 }'
```

In this case the `%` sign is ignored in the arithmetic expression. I don't know `df` rounds the percentage to the nearest integer, as I have assumed. If it rounds down, then `100-$5` will be rounded up, so instead use `99-$5` to get the free space rounded down.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't show exactly what the desired output is but this seems to match what you want:

```
df -h | grep -E --color=never 'Filesystem|/dev/'
```

The string `Filesystem` is included so that the output shows the human-friendly column headers.  The `/dev/` string is included because it eliminates the udev and tmpfs systems.